# Icinga: Installing icinga2 gives unmet dependencies errors

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am on a Ubuntu 17.04 Server and when trying to install Icinga2 per the [instructions](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#getting-started), I get a dependency error.

```
root@PC:~# apt-get install icinga2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 icinga2 : Depends: icinga2-bin (= 2.6.3-1~ppa1~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried running apt-get install icinga2-bin and get the following

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
icinga2-bin : Depends: libicinga2 (= 2.6.3-1~ppa1~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libboost-program-options1.58.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-system1.58.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-thread1.58.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/665251 see if this works for you

Comment: You are using third-party PPA. First remove that to  resolve dependency issue.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libicinga2 icinga2-bin libboost-system1.58.0` and `apt-get install -sf libboost-system1.58.0`?

Comment: Unticked the repositories and it seemed to do the trick.